# Phone can't connect to Eclipse on debug mode

Tags: android, memory, file-transfer

I have tried connecting the USB debugger on Samsung Galaxy S2 and Samsung Galaxy Nexus. It still manages to fail on both devices. At the moment I am using Windows XP and I am running out of ideas.

Here is what I tried:

1. Installed SAMSUNG_USB_DRIVER_FOR_MOBILE_PHONES_1.4.8.0.exe
2. Searched and tried to install the drivers on Google drives.

Has anyone have this similar problem and could share a solution?

EDIT* Both devices Samsung Galaxy S2 and Samsung Galaxy Nexus are able to connect to the PC but not to the debugger. Drivers installed with different variances even done installing Samsung Kias.

I am adding a bounty tomorrow for 50 reps. I really need to test what I am doing on an actual phone.

Comment: You did enable USB debugging on the phones, right?

Comment: Yes I have followed that much and the 2 steps

Comment: I don't own a SGS2, but as far as the Galaxy Nexus is concerned, the ADB drivers bundled with the SDK worked fine for me, also on WinXP. Same goes for my Galaxy Nexus S.

Comment: That's what I am wondering. I have the drivers it connects to the PC but it doesn't show anything on the DDMS or another device on it, other than the virtual devices.

Comment: Try restarting server using adb kill-server.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not familiar with adding "adb kill-server" could you guide me on how to do it?.

Comment: On Windows, open a command prompt, run [adb kill-server](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#commandsummary), this will force a adb server restart.

Comment: Maybe try linux instead? Much easier to get things set up there :D

Comment: Can't switch OS system just like that :P. @yorkw sorry for the long wait I was gone for a bit, on command prompt prompts it is not an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Either setup the environment variable (see [How to update your PATH](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#sdkContents)), Or open prompt at SDK install folder ../android-sdk/platform-tools to run the adb command.

Comment: @yorkw Thanks for the knowledge. I can now confirm......It still doesn't connect D:.

Comment: Can you rightclick MyComputer->Manage->Devices and view your phone. Is there an explanation point by your device or does it say drivers are installed and it is functioning normally? Also don't turn on USB Storage

Comment: @KDEx No exclamation point and USB storage is off. Also want to add device does exist.

Comment: Well you have three variables. Eliminate each one one at a time. First try a different USB cable (this actually fixed the same problem for me the other day) Then you can try a factory reset of the phone (a pain) and then try reinstalling the entire SDK (a real pain)

Comment: Yup....It looks like the 3rd thing might be the only thing I haven't tried yet.

Comment: Curious.... Have you ever been able to connect any physical device to that installation of eclipse on that machine?

Answer (score 1):

You need to download [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/) I know that the software description doesn't mention that it is the correct drivers for developers, but it in fact is.

Comment: I already tried downloading samsun kias. It is also inside my computer

Answer (score 0):

An old issue used to be:

Use the USB2.0 ports on the back of the PC not the 1.0 front facing port.

Comment: I tried it just now. There is no effect on the DDMS on all ports

Comment: Are you saying you can't deploy your app to the phone, or you just can't hit breakpoints after deploying?

Comment: My phone can't connect to the eclipse ddms system. So I can't load the phone with my apk and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you have not installed sdk properly. Reinstall the http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r18-windows.exe, the open the adb and update all the things for the particular sdk you want.

Then verify that you have given the exact location of sdk in eclipse>window>preferences>android

Then restart eclipse.

Even you cant open it then set environment variables. For that add following **;E:\android-sdk-window\platform-tools;** in PATH. Then restart windows.

After that try **adb devices**, **adb kill-server** command in Command prompt.
You will be able to see your device.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any "ADB interface" devices in your PC's Devices Manager?
If you are using DDMS,Maybe there is a console(cmd.exe) window behind DDMS,you can get some log there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the debug mode on your device? This is not listed in the steps you followed.
Go to Settings -> Applications -> Development -> and set USB debugging.

Comment: I did enable debugging on the device

Answer (score 0):

You can use PdaNet software to connect your device for debugging. I was have the same issue and resolve with using this software. Use the following link to download this software:

http://junefabrics.com/android/download.php

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I tried this now the idea is a cool concept but it still doesn't work. I really have no idea what is going on.

Comment: are u using your personal computer or office computer? Because in office network guys have some security setting so this problem occurs. You can check ADB Interface is installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

I also have samsung Galaxy SII and i face the Same Problem before some days. But now i am able to get debug the app in My SII.

Please follow the steps and make sure that you follow it completely then only you cna able to get debug in your phone.

First select the Option to Install App from Unknown Sources.
You will find that option in Setting -> Applicatios -> Unknown sources. Select it as yes.

then Select the Option like USB Debugging.
You will find that option in Setting -> Development -> USB debugging. Select it as yes.

Now, Install latest Samsung Kias In your PC. Reboot Your PC, Eclipse and may be Phone also

Now, Try with connecting the Device.

Hope you will get debugging your app in to your phone.

If not then let me know which trouble you get.

Enjoy. :)

Comment: Same thing I am still not able to debug and can't see the device on eclipse. I can however just transfer files between computers.

Comment: you're using windows right? have you tried running the adb with administrator permissions? because this is the same thing i had on my ubuntu and by using sudo it started showing up in `adb devices` before that it wasn't showing neither in the console nor eclispe

Answer (score 0):

My phone has this:
       Settings -> SD card & phone storage -> Mass storage only (USB connection mode is mass storage only)

Make sure that this option is NOT checked. If it is u can enable USB debugging and unknown sources and it still wont work.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to connect to the device for install and debugging you can manually select the driver to use when you plug it in.

Don't let windows search for it, choose I will pick the driver from a list, then select android composite ADB interface. It may warn you that this driver doesn't match, but it works!

Comment: I did this steps with numerous times I reinstalled different drivers

Answer (score 0):

I also had many problems to get samsumg galaxy S2 work on my pc. If I remember correctly finally I ended up installing Samsung Kias and installed some drivers through there. Then restarted the computer and never launched kias from then on. My phone is still not visible form command line `adb devices`, but now I can develop in Eclipse and deploy on the device without any problems.

From time to time I lose connection to the device (E.g. if another device was plugged in). Then I need to restart Eclipse and my device becomes visible again.

Some friends of mine also shared that some other mobile device usb drivers were conflicting with the samsung drivers (it was ZTE if I am not wrong). They uninstalled the ZTE drivers and then got the Samsuung running ok too. Try consider uninstalling all other usb drivers before you try the Galaxy S2.

Comment: Yeah still an error waiting for http://android.modaco.com/topic/322611-official-zte-usb-drivers/ to load up.

Comment: @sdfwer Crap, maybe I didn't made myself clear. I meant you should NOT have ZTE drivers installed, not the contrary. Make sure the drivers you get from Kias are the only ones installed on the computer.

Comment: I had Kias as the only drivers from samsung it still didn't show when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed exactly the right SDK version for the phone you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you can access the phone on the PC via KIES, I assume that you have all the correct USB drivers installed.

1. Ensure that debugging is enabled on your phone. This can be done from the Settings preferences.
2. Install the Android SDK. Add `%ANDROID SDK_INSTALL_PATH%/platform-tools` to your path.
3. If everything is working up to this point, plug in your phone and execute the following from the command line.

   `adb devices`

   and you should see your device listed.
4. Install the Android Developer Tools plugin in Eclipse.
5. Create/Import your project.
6. Right click your project and from the context menu, select Debug As --> Android Application

Answer (score 0):

I have had exactly the same problem as you, I even gave up on developing for 2 months because of this.  I have just started again and really needed to get this working.

I tried all of the above and pretty much every combination of the above and still failed.

I have just got it working by not doing anything different apart from when I uninstall the old USB driver (add remove progs), the next time I installed AGAIN, I used the SAMSUNG USB Driver for Mobile Phones V1.3.450.0 (an older version than ones suggested on other help forums, I just got it by accident somewhere and thought I'd try it).  The next time I plugged the phone in, it did all the usual finding CDC etc. that it always did when it failed...but then.... it asked for the ADB Driver, WOW!  I got excited.  I just selected Install Automatically and away it went.

I still already had the PDANet thing running and that popped up saying a connection is available.  I've not used it though because it wouldn't install on my phone anyway.

FYI, I have these settings on the phone:

USB debugging ON (obviously)

Allow Mock Locations OFF

Unknown Sources ON

I hope this helps.

Dan.

Answer (score 0):

This may not help at all since you have probably tried it already but I had huge issues on two different windows 7 machines getting my s2 to connect for debugging.

I ended up getting one working by plugging in the s2 USB connection, un-installing the drivers for it in the device manager, unplugging the USB connection, un-installing Kies, downloading the most up to date version of Kies, installing that and plugging it back in.

The other one was even more painful, it was a while ago now but I did the same as the above but removed eclipse and the Android SDK as well, installed the latest version of Kies first, the eclipse, then the sdk and made sure all of that was done before I plugged the phone in.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue which you faced..

I solved this by this way.

```
1) Right click on my computer and select Manage
2) Then select Device manager..
3) connect your phone (galaxy s2 in my case)
4) I found one device with named "unknown" in sub option I foung my phone name i9100
5) Then right click on that and select update driver software
6) you will see then this..
```

[image: SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface]

Tadaa....Done :)

Hope this will help you also..